# (Push + Dropdown) button wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I need a control that have a push button and a dropdown button.

e.g.

[image: this button is available in ribbon control]

Similar control is available in `wxRibbonButtonBar` , I am not able to use it in simple wxPanel.

Answer (score 5):

I implemented SplitButton and It look like:

[image]

**SplitButton.h**

```
#ifndef __SPLIT_BUTTON_H__
#define __SPLIT_BUTTON_H__

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/menu.h>

class SplitButton : public wxPanel
{
public:
    SplitButton(wxWindow *parent,
        wxWindowID id,
        const wxString& label,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize);

    ~SplitButton();

    wxMenu* GetSplitButtonMenu();

protected:
    void OnKillFocus(wxFocusEvent& event);
    void OnMouseLeave(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnMouseEnter(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnLeftButtonUp(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnLeftButtonDown(wxMouseEvent& event);
    void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& WXUNUSED(event));

    bool Enable(bool enable = true) override;

private:
    int m_stateButton = 0;
    int m_stateMenu = 0;
    bool m_bIsEnable = true;
    wxColor m_colorNormal;
    wxColor m_colorDisabled;
    const int m_arrowButtonWidth = 20;
    bool m_bLButtonDown = false;
    wxString m_label;
    wxMenu* m_pMenu = nullptr;
};

#endif /*__SPLIT_BUTTON_H__*/
```

**SplitButton.cpp**

```
#include "SplitButton.h"
#include <wx/renderer.h>

SplitButton::SplitButton(wxWindow *parent,
    wxWindowID id,
    const wxString& label,
    const wxPoint& pos,
    const wxSize& size)
    : wxPanel(parent, id, pos, size, wxBORDER_NONE | wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, "DropDownButton"),
    m_label(label)
{
    m_colorNormal = GetForegroundColour();
    m_colorDisabled = GetForegroundColour().MakeDisabled();

    if (size == wxDefaultSize)
    {
        wxSize defaultSize = wxButton::GetDefaultSize();

        wxSize textSize = GetTextExtent(m_label);
        textSize.SetWidth(textSize.GetWidth() + m_arrowButtonWidth + 20);
        SetMinSize(wxSize(textSize.GetWidth(), defaultSize.GetHeight()));
    }

    Bind(wxEVT_PAINT, &SplitButton::OnPaint, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_UP, &SplitButton::OnLeftButtonUp, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, &SplitButton::OnLeftButtonDown, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_KILL_FOCUS, &SplitButton::OnKillFocus, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, &SplitButton::OnMouseLeave, this);
    Bind(wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW, &SplitButton::OnMouseEnter, this);

    m_pMenu = new wxMenu();
}

SplitButton::~SplitButton()
{
    delete m_pMenu;
    m_pMenu = nullptr;
}

wxMenu* SplitButton::GetSplitButtonMenu()
{
    return m_pMenu;
}

void SplitButton::OnKillFocus(wxFocusEvent& event)
{
    m_stateButton = wxCONTROL_CURRENT;
    m_stateMenu = wxCONTROL_CURRENT;
    Refresh();

    event.Skip();
}

void SplitButton::OnMouseLeave(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    m_stateButton = 0;
    m_stateMenu = 0;
    Refresh();

    event.Skip();
}

void SplitButton::OnMouseEnter(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    m_stateButton = wxCONTROL_CURRENT;
    m_stateMenu = wxCONTROL_CURRENT;
    Refresh();

    event.Skip();
}

void SplitButton::OnLeftButtonUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    m_stateButton = 0;
    m_stateMenu = 0;

    Refresh();

    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    event.GetPosition(&x, &y);

    if (x < (GetSize().GetWidth() - m_arrowButtonWidth))
    {
        wxEvtHandler* pEventHandler = GetEventHandler();
        wxASSERT(pEventHandler);

        pEventHandler->CallAfter([=]()
        {
            wxCommandEvent evt(wxEVT_BUTTON, this->GetId());
            evt.SetEventObject(this);
            GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(evt);
        });
    }

    m_bLButtonDown = false;

    event.Skip();
}

void SplitButton::OnLeftButtonDown(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
    m_bLButtonDown = true;

    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;
    event.GetPosition(&x, &y);

    if (x >= (GetSize().GetWidth() - m_arrowButtonWidth))
    {
        m_stateButton = 0;
        m_stateMenu = wxCONTROL_PRESSED;
        Refresh();

        wxSize size = GetSize();
        wxPoint position;
        position.x = 0;
        position.y = size.GetHeight();
        PopupMenu(m_pMenu, position);

        m_stateMenu = 0;
        Refresh();
    }
    else
    {
        m_stateButton = wxCONTROL_PRESSED;
        m_stateMenu = wxCONTROL_PRESSED;
        Refresh();
    }

    event.Skip();
}

void SplitButton::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    wxSize size = GetSize();
    const int width = size.GetWidth() - m_arrowButtonWidth;

    // Draw first part of button
    wxRect r1;
    r1.x = 0;
    r1.y = 0;
    r1.width = width + 2;
    r1.height = size.GetHeight();

    wxRendererNative::Get().DrawPushButton(this, dc, r1, m_stateButton);

    SetForegroundColour(m_bIsEnable ? m_colorNormal : m_colorDisabled);

    r1.y += (size.GetHeight() - GetCharHeight()) / 2;
    dc.DrawLabel(m_label, r1, wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    // Draw second part of button
    wxRect r2;
    r2.x = width - 2;
    r2.y = 0;
    r2.width = m_arrowButtonWidth;
    r2.height = size.GetHeight();

    wxRendererNative::Get().DrawPushButton(this, dc, r2, m_stateMenu);
    wxRendererNative::Get().DrawDropArrow(this, dc, r2, m_stateMenu);
}

bool SplitButton::Enable(bool enable)
{
    m_bIsEnable = enable;
    wxPanel::Enable(m_bIsEnable);

    if (m_bIsEnable)
    {
        m_stateButton = 0;
        m_stateMenu = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        m_stateButton = wxCONTROL_DISABLED;
        m_stateMenu = wxCONTROL_DISABLED;
    }

    wxPaintEvent event;
    ProcessEvent(event);
    Refresh();

    return enable;
}
```

Comment: This looks perfect. I'll have a look. BTW you wrote this answer on my birthday!

Answer (score 1):

There is no wxwidgets for this kind of button. But if you are using win32 and has wxwidgets 3.1+, you can try nativewindow

See the sample file shipped with wxwidget package

%wxpath%\wxWidgets-3.1.0\samples\widgets\native.cpp

```
class NativeWindow : public wxNativeWindow
{
public:
    explicit NativeWindow(wxWindow* parent)
        : wxNativeWindow()
    {
        // When creating the native window, we must specify the valid parent
        // and while we don't have to specify any position if it's going to be
        // laid out by sizers, we do need the size.
        const wxSize size = FromDIP(wxSize(140, 30));

        HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindow
                      (
                        TEXT("BUTTON"),
                        TEXT("Press me to do it"),
                        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_SPLITBUTTON,
                        0, 0, size.x, size.y,
                        (HWND)parent->GetHWND(), 0, NULL, NULL
                      );
        if ( !hwnd )
        {
            wxLogError("Creating split button failed.");
            return;
        }

        (void)Create(parent, wxID_ANY, hwnd);
    }
```

[image]

Update: A workaround is to use two buttons to simulate the combined button, don't forget to set wxBU_EXACTFIT and adjust the boards
[image]

Comment: I am using wx 3.0 and I need this control on Mac as well.

Comment: @Anil8753 you can also use two buttons as workaround, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using `wxNativeWindow` too with 3.1+, but there is another solution which might work for you and which is available in 3.0: use `wxToolBar` and add a tool using `wxITEM_DROPDOWN` style.

Comment: wxToolbar with wxITEM_DROPDOWN  tool is helpful, but not perfect. I has transparent background and on mouse hover it shows full button. I need it's mouse hover state always visible

Comment: @Anil8753 you can try modify the source code of WX.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at wxOwnderDrawComboBox.