# wxPopupTransientWindow not showing content correctly

Tags: c++, popup, wxwidgets

I'm creating a C++ wxWidgets calculator application. I'm implementing trigonometric functions, and to save on space I've reunited all of them in a single button. If you right click on the button then, a popup is created, which contains buttons for all the functions. I'm using a derived wxPopupTransientWindow class for this job, the problem is, the buttons aren't displaying correctly.

[image: Popup problem]

This is my code:

**expandMenu.h**

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/popupwin.h"

struct expandMenuInfo
{
    const wxString& label;
    wxWindowID id;

    expandMenuInfo(const wxString& l, wxWindowID i)
        : label{l}
        , id{i}
    {}
};

class expandMenu : public wxPopupTransientWindow
{
    wxWindow* panel;
    wxBoxSizer* sizer;

public:
    expandMenu(wxWindow* parent, wxPoint pos, std::vector<expandMenuInfo> buttons);
    ~expandMenu();
};
```

**expandMenu.cpp**

```
#include "expandMenu.h"

// PANNELLO ESTENSIONE

expandMenu::expandMenu(wxWindow* parent, wxPoint pos, std::vector<expandMenuInfo> buttons)
    : wxPopupTransientWindow(parent, wxBORDER_NONE | wxPU_CONTAINS_CONTROLS)
{
    this->SetPosition(pos);
    this->SetSize(50 * buttons.size(), 50);

    this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(90, 93, 121));

    panel = new wxWindow(this, wxID_ANY);
    sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

    // costruisci struttura
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++)
    {
        wxButton* btn = new wxButton(this, buttons.at(i).id, buttons.at(i).label);
        sizer->Add(btn, 1, wxEXPAND);
    }
    panel->SetSizer(sizer);
}

expandMenu::~expandMenu()
{
}
```

And this is the code I use for my custom wxButton's to actually create the popup (it's temporary):

```
void ikeButton::rightClick(wxMouseEvent& evt) // CREA PANNELLO ESTENSIONE
{
    if (flags & EXPANDABLE)
    {
        std::vector<expandMenuInfo> buttons;
        buttons.push_back(expandMenuInfo(L"sin", 3001));
        buttons.push_back(expandMenuInfo(L"cos", 3002));
        buttons.push_back(expandMenuInfo(L"tan", 3003));

        expandMenu* menu = new expandMenu(this, wxGetMousePosition(), buttons);
        menu->Popup();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help, as I'm pretty new to this framework.

Comment: why? Can't you just create `wxComboBox` for that?

Comment: I want the sine button to do its thing on left click and to open the menu on right click. The buttons inside the menu need to be placed in a grid, and when one of them is selected, I want the sine button to turn into the button that was pressed. Is all of this possible to achieve with a single wxComboBox?

Comment: I'm thinking of using wxComboBox to select the appropriate functions. Please check the docs for the control screenshot and `widgets` sample for control behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the buttons to layout in the popup window, in the constuctor for expandMenu I think you just need to change `panel->SetSizer(sizer);` to

```
    SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
    Layout();
```

---

From a UI perspective, I think a [split button](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/split-buttons/) might be a better way to implement the functionality you are describing.  wxWidgets doesn't currently  have such a control, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076881/push-dropdown-button-wxwidgets) shows 2 different ways you can create one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you're specifying `this` for the parent of the buttons, i.e. the popup window. I think you wanted their parent to be the *panel* instead.