# Can't figure out how to setup wxPopupTransientWindow properly | wxWidgets | C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm trying to set up a Pop-up window, the problem is all the samples online make custom wxPopupTransientWindow windows, I can't figure out how to make one using only the constructor (like you make most wx components ex: `wxPanel* P = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(50, 50), 0);`).

Here's the code I have right now

```
wxPopupTransientWindow* PopupWindow = new wxPopupTransientWindow(this, wxBORDER_NONE);
PopupWindow->SetSize(50, 50);
PopupWindow->SetPosition(wxDefaultPosition);
```

The error code I get

```cpp
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(59,1): error C2201: 'const `public: __cdecl MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const &,wxPoint const &,wxSize const &)'::`2'::wxPopupWindowBase::`vftable'': must have external linkage in order to be exported/imported
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(38,14): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindowBase::~wxPopupWindowBase': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(53,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindowBase::Position': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(52,5): error C2071: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::ms_classInfo': illegal storage class
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(52,5): error C2246: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::ms_classInfo': illegal static data member in locally defined class
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(53,1): error C2201: 'const `public: __cdecl MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const &,wxPoint const &,wxSize const &)'::`2'::wxPopupWindow::`vftable'': must have external linkage in order to be exported/imported
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(28,14): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::~wxPopupWindow': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(30,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::SetFocus': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(31,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::Show': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(34,21): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::MSWGetStyle': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(37,20): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::MSWGetParent': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\msw\popupwin.h(52,5): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupWindow::GetClassInfo': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(125,1): error C2201: 'const `public: __cdecl MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const &,wxPoint const &,wxSize const &)'::`2'::wxPopupTransientWindowBase::`vftable'': must have external linkage in order to be exported/imported
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(112,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindowBase::Destroy': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(153,5): error C2071: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::ms_classInfo': illegal storage class
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(153,5): error C2246: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::ms_classInfo': illegal static data member in locally defined class
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(155,1): error C2201: 'const `public: __cdecl MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const &,wxPoint const &,wxSize const &)'::`2'::wxPopupTransientWindow::`vftable'': must have external linkage in order to be exported/imported
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(138,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::Popup': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(139,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::Dismiss': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(142,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::MSWHandleMessage': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(148,18): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::MSWDismissUnfocusedPopup': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
1>C:\Users\husse\C++\Data-Mange-Bot-C++ver\DataManageApp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\wx\popupwin.h(153,5): error C3640: 'MyFrame::{ctor}::wxPopupTransientWindow::GetClassInfo': a referenced or virtual member function of a local class must be defined
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68044788/wxpopuptransientwindow-not-showing-content-correctly

Comment: @Pal, did you check wxWidgets samples?

Comment: @Igor, wxWidgets samples are far too advanced for most people!! Also, the samples are fairly outdated; most still use event tables and connect!

Comment: @macroland, you should talk to Vadim about that. ;-)  In terms of complexity - wxWidgets is a complex library and you need to know C++ (not be a beginner) to use it. In terms of event tables and connect usage - yes it should benefit to change it. But again - see above.

Comment: @macroland Yea the samples are a bit hard to follow, anyways the question you sent should do the trick, I shall nick it. thanks

Comment: Yes, because they are "samples" and not "examples" :)